# Remove field form mysql

Tags: mysql

My database has two table
Table A contain two field (id,numar)
Table B contain two field (numar)
How to remove row form Table A  AND B Where A.numar not exist B.numar AND B.numar not exist A.numar
Great thanks

Comment: from which table do you want to remove rows?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE Numar NOT IN (SELECT Numar FROM TableB)
DELETE FROM TableB WHERE Numar NOT IN (SELECT Numar FROM TableA)
```

So if your tables had this data:

```
id|numar    id|numar
--------    --------
1 | 01      1 | 02
2 | 02      2 | 03
3 | 03      3 | 04
4 | 04      4 | 05
```

Then the first statement would remove row id 1 from the first table, and then the second statement would remove row id 4 from the second table.

Comment: @Thoman: Maybe there aren't any instances where it's in one table and not another, but instead there are instances of duplicates?  That's an entirely different issue.

Comment: SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE TableA.numar NOT IN (SELECT numar FROM tableB)
MySQL returned an empty result set

Comment: @Thoman: That would indicate to me that there are no records in `TableA` for which the `numar` value does not exist in `TableB`.  So it sounds like there's nothing to remove based on your criteria.